# How to prevent reloading a component while clicking back in Angular6 without using Service?

Tags: angular, typescript, angular-ui-router

Lets consider 2 angular components **componentA** and **componentB**, i have a Form with some values entered in **componentA** with a button to navigate to the **componentB**, after navigating to **componentB** i have a back button to go back to **componentA**, now after clicking back button it navigates to **componentA** but with values reloaded (the entire component refreshed), how can i prevent reloading the component while clicking back, please help me out.

I'm using `routerLink='./componentA'` for routing back

Answer (score 1):

You have to store your form's controls value temporary. You can create a service and keep all that form's data in that service property.

If you want that data after refreshing the page then store it in browser e.g. in Local storage, Session storage or cookies(depends on your requirement).

And pre populate your ComponentA form via these stored value.

Comment: Is there anyother way without using services, because i'm looking for methods without service calling

Comment: No i do not think so...Service's state does not reset or reinitialises automatically because these are singleton. But components state gets reset whenever these were called.

Comment: thanks for the suggestion @Praveen Gupta, i'll try to work on it

Comment: @sivaIT have you got the solution for your question? if yes please share with me, i need it.

Answer (score 0):

Try using Locatoin Service. import it form `import {Location} from '@angular/common';`
then inject it in **componentB**.

```
constructor(private _location: Location) 
  {}

  onClickBack() {
    this._location.back();
  }
```

Comment: the component still gets refreshed.

Comment: Not even close to answering the question.